# Is it possible to un-blit an image?

Tags: python, list, pygame, rect, blit

In my scenario, I have heart canisters that are blitted onto the screen, and rects for the heart canisters added to a list. When my player hits the heart canister, I want the heart canister and the rect to disappear. I have all the collision set up so that when the player hits the heart, its rect is removed from the list, but I cannot figure out how to un-blit/remove the heart canister from the screen. Here is my relavent code...

```
def room_2(): #Only called once, when player enters room
    global tile_rects
    global heart_rects
    global halfheart_rects
    global r_x 
    global r_y
    global room
    room = room2
    tile_rects = []
    heart_rects = [] 
    halfheart_rects = [] #List for halfheart_rects being emptied
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    r_y = 0
    for layer in room2: #Loop through an array, and translate numbers from the array to things                   on screen
        r_x = 0
        for tile in layer:  
            if tile == '4':
                screen.blit(floor_halfheart, (r_x*40- 8, r_y*40)) #Blit heart in location wanted
                halfheart_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 39, 39)) #Add rect to list
            if tile == '3':
                bat_create()
            if tile == '2':
                screen.blit(stone_block, (r_x*40, r_y*40))
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 40, 40))                     
            if tile == '1':
                screen.blit(stone_wall, (r_x*40, r_y*40))    
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 39, 39))
            r_x += 1
        r_y += 1 

for hh in halfheart_rects: #Loop through halfheart_rects list
    halfheart_collision = player_rect.colliderect(hh) #Collision between player and single heart
    if halfheart_collision:
        if player_health < player_health_max: 
            player_health += 1
            room[hh.y // 40][hh.x//40] = '0' #Removing heart canister number from array for when nect entering room
            halfheart_rects.remove(hh)
```

I tried covering the location where the heart canister is with a coloured rect in `if player_health < player_health_max:` but the following lines only get run once, so the rect flashed then dissapears. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `Loop through halfheart_rects list` you are modifying a list while iterating over it. That's generally considered a very bad idea – items will unexpectedly be skipped. Perhaps that is the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn this into 2 functions, 1 for setting everything up and 1 for drawing because you should be blitting the heart canisters every frame, not once. This means you dont need to unblit you can just not blit the old one will get covered up. You could also move them to the function where you are drawing the player. The general setup should be like

```
def draw_screen():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    player.draw()
    for heart in halfheart_rects:
        screen.blit(floor_halfheart, (hear.x, heart.y)) 

def setup_room_2()
    global tile_rects
    global heart_rects
    global halfheart_rects
    global r_x 
    global r_y
    global room
    room = room2
    tile_rects = []
    heart_rects = [] 
    halfheart_rects = []
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    r_y = 0
    for layer in room2:
        r_x = 0
        for tile in layer:  
            if tile == '4':
                halfheart_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 39, 39))
            if tile == '3':
                bat_create()
            if tile == '2':
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 40, 40))                     
            if tile == '1':    
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(r_x*40, r_y*40, 39, 39))
            r_x += 1
        r_y += 1 


while running:
    draw_screen()
    if player_enters_room_1:
        setup_room_1()
    elif player_enters_room_2:
        setup_room_2()
for hh in halfheart_rects:
    halfheart_collision = player_rect.colliderect(hh)
    if halfheart_collision:
        if player_health < player_health_max: 
            player_health += 1
            room[hh.y // 40][hh.x//40] 
            halfheart_rects.remove(hh)
```

the for loop at the end is bad as when you remove one from the list, lets say its the 2nd, the 3rd becomes the 2nd, so the loop skips it and goes to the 3rd (which was the 4th)

if this doesnt help, put the code where you draw everything and i will have a look.